# Create Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have the following syntax for creating a stored procedure in MySQL 5.0.10

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE getTweets (var1 varchar(100))
LANGUAGE SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'A procedure to return 20 least scored tweets based on the temp sessionid of the user'
BEGIN
    SELECT count(ts.tweetid) as "count",t.id as "tweetid", t.tweettext as "tweet"
    FROM tweets t
    LEFT JOIN tweetscores ts ON t.id = ts.tweetid
    where t.id not in (select distinct(tweetid) from tweetscores where  temp_sessionid=var1)
    group by t.id, t.tweettext order by count   
    LIMIT 10;
END//
```

i keep on getting the error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 12

can anybody spot the error..

Comment: Works for me. How do you execute it?

Comment: Try keeping the delimiter in next line

Comment: @juergend just clicked on the `go` button in phpmyadmin...

Comment: @Sai done that but no effect...

Comment: @dakait: Remove the `delimiter //` part. In PHPMyAdmin you dont need it I think.

Comment: @juergend  im using phpmyadmin ... is there someother way of creating proc in it plz guide

Comment: @juergend voila!!! post it as answer plz.....

Comment: @dakait, do it through command line, it works great.

Comment: @Sai thanks for ur time, it worked indeed when executed from command line, as juergen suggested the problem was PhpMyAdmin doesnot require the delimiters to be specified explicitly ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query works when executing it as a script on DB level.

But using PhpMyAdmin you need remove the `delimiter` statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTweets (var1 varchar(100))
LANGUAGE SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'A procedure to return 20 least scored tweets based on the temp sessionid of the user'
BEGIN
    SELECT count(ts.tweetid) as "count",t.id as "tweetid", t.tweettext as "tweet"
    FROM tweets t
    LEFT JOIN tweetscores ts ON t.id = ts.tweetid
    where t.id not in (select distinct(tweetid) from tweetscores where  temp_sessionid=var1)
    group by t.id, t.tweettext order by count   
    LIMIT 10;
end
```

PhpMyAdmin will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTweets (var1 varchar(100))
LANGUAGE SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'A procedure to return 20 least scored tweets based on the temp sessionid of the user'
BEGIN
    SELECT count(ts.tweetid) as "count",t.id as "tweetid", t.tweettext as "tweet"
    FROM tweets t
    LEFT JOIN tweetscores ts ON t.id = ts.tweetid
    where t.id not in (select distinct(tweetid) from tweetscores where  temp_sessionid=var1)
    group by t.id, t.tweettext order by count   
    LIMIT 10;
end
```